# git push force is rejected after reset --hard

Tags: git

Our branching model says that on `master` branch should be the current production state.

Accindently a develop version was merged from `developed` into `master` and pushed by one of our new colleages. So on `master` there's not our production state any more. I want to revert this to apply a hotfix but I fail.

To know all commits I first pulled the current `master`:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then, like said in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872223/how-do-i-revert-master-branch-to-a-tag-in-git), I try to reset my local `master` using

```
git reset --hard <versiontag>
git push --force origin master
```

But the forced push is rejected because the are "future" commits.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To [URL OF MY REPO]
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '[URL OF MY REPO]'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Yeah I know that there are commits. And I want to remove them from `master` because they don't belong there (yet, until `develop` is meant to be merged into `master`)

How can I successfully revert my master branch to a current tag and then push this to remote or asked in another way - how can I get rid of the wrong merged commits in my `master` branch?

Comment: Take a look at your git configuration, perhaps `receive.denyNonFastForwards`, 
`receive.denyDeletes` are set? Or, if you're using github, perhaps there's a hook involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a `reset` and `push --force` you need to change the settings on your sever. On a plain git server, make sure that the following config options are not set:

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
receive.denyDeletes
```

On other servers, e.g. github, gitlab, bitbucket, this can be done through the web interface.

Your other options is to create a new commit that reverts the changes you don't want. `git revert` will assist you in doing this.  This would be preferable if other people have already pulled the commits you want to revert.

Comment: As our sever is centralized administrated I can't change the settings there. So I think I have to try to revert the changes manually. Thank you for showing this server side option I didn't know before.