# How do I use my gitlab personal access token in my jelastic jps manifests?

Tags: gitlab, jelastic

Until now, I have always been working with public repositories, where everything is smooth and easy. However, I would like to now switch to private repos.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022209/how-to-version-a-private-jelastic-environment/54040812#54040812) related to github repos. Unfortunately, it seems like it doesn't work the same for gitlab. In particular, the `?access_token=${settings.accessToken}` does not seem to be recognized well by gitlab.

How should I proceed with my gitlab access token? What I was able to figure out until now (but I find this a little bit crap), is that I should replace

```sh
baseUrl: https://www.my-gitlab.com/my-company/my-project/my-repo/-/raw/master

onInstall:
  - cmd:
    - curl -fsSL ${baseUrl}/my-folder/my-script.sh | /bin/sh 
    - wget ${baseUrl}/my-folder/my-script.sh -O my-script.sh
```

with

```sh
globals:
  GITLAB_API_URL: http://www.my-gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/my-project-id/repository/files

onInstall:
  - cmd:
    - curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${settings.accessToken}" -fsSL ${globals.GITLAB_API_URL}/my-folder%2Fmy-script.sh/raw?ref=master | /bin/sh
    - wget --header="PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${settings.accessToken}" ${globals.GITLAB_API_URL}/my-folder%2Fmy-script.sh/raw?ref=master -O my-script.sh
```

But I find the above replacement a bit complicated. I'm pretty sure there must be something equivalent to what is done with github on gitlab. Also, the above replacement does not quite work. For example, the call

```sh
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${settings.accessToken}" -fsSL ${globals.GITLAB_API_URL}/my-folder%2Fmy-script.sh/raw?ref=master | /bin/sh
```

with `${settings.accessToken}` and `${globals.GITLAB_API_URL}` replaced with the relevant values, works fine on my development PC; however, when that command runs on jelastic, I get the error

```
/bin/bash: line 1: {curl -H \"PRIVATE-TOKEN:<my-token>\" -fsSL http://www.my-gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/my-project-id/repository/files/my-folder/my-script.sh/raw?ref=master | /bin/sh}: No such file or directory","nodeid":63261,"exitStatus":127,"out":""}
```

I have no clue why that does not work and I guess using the gitlab api is not the right way to get my stuff done with `curl` and `wget`. Also, I have no clue how to get stuff like this working:

```yaml
onInstall:
  install:
    jps: ${baseUrl}/jelastic/tools.jps?access_token=${settings.accessToken}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: This functionality is planned to be added soon, but no ETA so far.